# incompatible type between string and StringProperty

Tags: java, string, javafx

i'm following many tutorials about how to fill a JFXTreeTableView

i wrote exactly the same code, and import the same packages and i'm getting this type of errors

```
Error:(137, 52) java: incompatible types: com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String cannot be converted to java.lang.String
```

there is the code

```
class User extends RecursiveTreeObject<User> {

    StringProperty userName;
    StringProperty age;
    StringProperty department;

    public User(String department, String age, String userName) {
        this.department = new SimpleStringProperty(department); //departement is underlined 
        this.userName = new SimpleStringProperty(userName); //userName is underlined
        this.age = new SimpleStringProperty(age); // age is underlined
    }
```

Comment: Are you using a String type other than the `java.lang.String`?

Comment: i found this in my import `com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String` ...

Comment: Did you add that import for a reason? Do you actually use this type? If not, simply remove that import. If you do, use the fully quallified class name for your constructor parameters: `public User(java.lang.String department, java.lang.String age, java.lang.String userName) ...`

Comment: this import has been added automatically and it is used! So there is a conflict between String Type, i just did what you told me and it's work, thanks man ;)

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that you actually need `com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String`. (The "internal" implies that you really should not be using this class.) Are you *sure* you are actually using it? What happens if you remove the import?

Comment: yeah, i tried to delete it and nothings happen! 
thanks all of you for your comment :D